# Cannot resolve android.media.MediaFile

Tags: android

I have android sdk 2.1 and it cannot resolve android.media.MediaFile package.

Why is it so? How can I solve this problem? To which version does android.media.MediaFile belong? Has it been deprecated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such library as I can see: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/package-summary.html

Comment: yeah, android 2.1 does not support it. Thats what am trying to determine, that which version supported it? Because it has been used in many programs. and if we encounter it, how can it be solved....

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else is seeing this issue...

After a lot of searching I discovered that this package is in recent Android builds (did not look back too far) but that Eclipse will still give this error if you try to import it into your project.

This appears to be because the class definition is 'hidden' using {@hide} tags in the source code (extract from platform_frameworks_base / media / java / android / media / MediaFile.java):

```
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Locale;

    /**
     * MediaScanner helper class.
     *
     * {@hide}
     */

    public class MediaFile {

    // Audio file types
    public static final int FILE_TYPE_MP3     = 1;
    public static final int FILE_TYPE_M4A     = 2;
    public static final int FILE_TYPE_WAV     = 3;
```

These tags appear to mean that Eclipse will not allow you use this class - the logic presumably being that it is a hidden API so you should not be using it anyway.

Some more information on the {@hide} tags is available at:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17056643/334402