# ViewRootImpl not in Android SDK

Tags: java, android

Just playing around a bit (I do know `View.getRootView()`), I manually stepped my way up to the root and even beyond.

```
...
View tv=(View)mv.getParent();
View uv=(View)tv.getParent();
...
```

Actually I thought that at one point I would run into a `NullPointerException`, but instead I got

```
03-18 13:07:45.554 13568 13568 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewRootImpl cannot be cast to android.view.View
```

Okay, fine, that looks reasonable, too.

I didn't know about `ViewRootImpl` yet, so I decided to pick up the topic and investigate it a bit.

However, when I do

```
ViewRootImpl wv=(View)vv.getParent();
```

I get a (deserved)

```
[javac] /home/jagged/Downloads/android/motog/firsttry/src/tk/wellthen/main.java:285: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : class ViewRootImpl
[javac] location: class tk.wellthen.main
[javac]     ViewRootImpl wv=(View)vv.getParent();
[javac]     ^
```

from the compiler, but still, when I fully qualify it according to the logcat output above, I get the (almost) same error message. (And I even copy-pasted it from the logcat output to avoid typos.)

Needless to say that upon trying to `import android.view.ViewRootImpl`. the same message appeared, just for another source line.

Also, Google doesn't seem to find it useful to mention it even with a single word throughout the API docs. I take it that it is mainly used for internals, but that's no reason if you ask me.

There are 138 hits for "`ViewRootImpl`" on stackoverflow.com (well, now it should be at least 139), but they are completely irrelevant in this context (if I didn't miss something special).

I've taken a look at some other sites, and found, for example, [this source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/view/ViewRootImpl.java), but I somehow doubt it'd be useful to *fake* it into the SDK in order to explore it?

Any advices? Thanks in advance

Comment: Related - the error you see has been logged as a bug against the platform here: [Issue 197291: AppCompatDialog crashes on selecting text](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=197291)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`ViewRootImpl` is annotated with `@hide`](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/ViewRootImpl.java#93). This excludes the class from the stub `android.jar` used for development. The class is there on an actual runtime environment.

See also: [What does @hide mean in the Android source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035271/what-does-hide-mean-in-the-android-source-code)

Answer (score -1):

If you use Eclipse, ViewRootImpl is invisible.
You can use the Android Studio instead.