# How to correctly create a draggable floating view?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-windowmanager, android-window

I use the following code to drag a view around the screen, and it works. But, when the user first touches `moveIcon`, the `floatingView` suddenly moves to the center of the screen, even though I want it to remain in its position. How can I fix this? I suspect the problem is in the *updatePosition()* method.

```
    windowManager = getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
    val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this)
    floatingView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.floating_layout, null)

    // Set up the layout parameters for the floating view
    val params = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY
        } else {
            @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE
        },
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
    )


    windowManager!!.addView(floatingView, params)

    // Moving the views:
    moveIcon = floatingView!!.findViewById(R.id.moveIcon)

    moveIcon.setOnTouchListener { view, event ->
        when (event.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                // Save the initial touch coordinates relative to the moveIcon view
                initialTouchX = event.rawX - view.x
                initialTouchY = event.rawY - view.y
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                // Calculate the new position based on the movement and initial touch coordinates
                val newX = event.rawX - initialTouchX
                val newY = event.rawY - initialTouchY

                updatePosition(newX.toInt(), newY.toInt())
            }
        }
        true
    }
}

private fun updatePosition(x: Int, y: Int) {
    val windowManager = getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager

    val layoutParams = floatingView!!.layoutParams as WindowManager.LayoutParams
    layoutParams.x = x
    layoutParams.y = y
    windowManager.updateViewLayout(floatingView, layoutParams)
}
```

Comment: Try looking at [DraggableView](https://android.gitzella.com/pkgs/hyuwah/DraggableView).

Comment: @AliasCartellano Thanks, but how can I use `moveIcon` to move `floatingView` like in my code using this library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The X/Y Coordinates of a view are defined in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#getX()) as the `translationX/Y` plus **the current** `left/top` property. The [Left](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#getLeft())/[Top](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#getTop()) position of a view are relative to its parent.

But, your `floatingView` is added directly through the `WindowManger`; and its parent here would be the [`ViewRootImpl`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22481051/9851608). So, you'd not expect that the left/top position of that view has the true values you need because `ViewRootImpl` is the system wide root View that is not accessible to developers; so, if you logged down the `view.x/y` you'll see them always `0`.

Instead of accessing `ViewRootImpl` from the Views directly, they offered the `WindowManger` API for that purpose. I.e., when the `floatingView` added to the `ViewRootImpl`; we didn't do `ViewRootImpl.addView()`, but we did `windowManager.addView()`.

Similarly, we need to get the x/y parameters through the `WindowManager` as well using the `WindowManager.LayoutParams` to get the right values:

```
....
MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {

//    initialTouchX = event.rawX - view.x // Remove this
//    initialTouchY = event.rawY - view.y // Remove this

    (floatingView.layoutParams as WindowManager.LayoutParams).let { params ->
        initialTouchX = event.rawX - params.x
        initialTouchY = event.rawY - params.y
    }

}
```