# Why can I not instantiate LocationManager class?

Tags: java, android, access-control

I am trying to do some work with LocationManager class and saw that I cannot instantiate it.

It is not an abstract class and I was under the impression that only classes marked as abstract could not be instantiated.

Comment: May be it constructor is private, if it's private you can not initialize outside of class

Comment: The constructor is private.  You have to get the system's LocationManager service from `Context#getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);`

Comment: *You* can't instantiate it directly, but something else you're using can and does (second paragraph of the docs). This is simple access control and is very common.

Comment: Well, that's something I missed and never realized. Thanks guys.

Comment: Keep up with the down votes guys, everyone here should be John Carmack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a more complete answer:

If you look at the [source code for LocationManager](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/location/java/android/location/LocationManager.java), specifically line 303, you'll see it actually *does* have a public constructor ... but there's a special annotation:

```
/**
 * @hide - hide this constructor because it has a parameter
 * of type ILocationManager, which is a system private class. The
 * right way to create an instance of this class is using the
 * factory Context.getSystemService.
 */
public LocationManager(Context context, ILocationManager service) {
    mService = service;
    mContext = context;
}
```

The `@hide` annotation keeps the constructor out of the Javadoc and the IDE won't show it. You can [read more about the @hide annotation in this SO Q and A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035271/what-does-hide-mean-in-the-android-source-code)

Basically, the class is designed so that you get it from the `Context` rather than instantiating it yourself. This is a fairly common design for things that require complex (or platform specific) configuration that you want to avoid having the user deal with.

Note that the `@hide` annotation and its handling are specific to Android.

This is similar to how the Builder or Factory pattern works, where only a builder/factory class can instantiate the object, although usually that's done with a private or package-private constructor in Java:

```
public class MyWidget
{
    private final Foo someObject; 
    // ... more stuff


    private MyWidget(Builder builder)
    {
        this.someObject = builder.someObject;
        // ... more stuff
    }

    public static class Builder
    {
        Foo someObject;

        public Builder() {}

        public Builder withFoo(Foo someObject)
        {
            this.someObject = someObject;
            return this;
        }

        public MyWidget build()
        {
            return new MyWidget(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Which gets invoked as:

```
MyWidget widget = new MyWidget.Builder().withFoo(someFoo).build();
```

Comment: Thank's a lot. I jut learned a lot from that post. Much appreciated.

Comment: @SpaceGhost True story; so did I. I've only played with Android a little and was expecting the standard idiom where the constructor was private or package-private - that's the answer I was *expecting* to type until I looked at the source. This is actually an interesting thing I didn't know about Android :)

Comment: Yeah, haha. I felt dumb asking but recalling what I knew about java, this stumped me a bit. I used google but didn't have much time to spare so every link I clicked didn't lead to an answer. 

Note to self: Look at source next time.