# Androids ObjectAnimator.ofFloat doesn't work properly

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I've used ObjectAnimator.ofFloat in an Android App which doesn't work on every device the same way.

*MainActivity (extends Activity):*

```
Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startAnimation();
    }
});


public void startAnimation() {
    ImageView aniView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    ObjectAnimator fadeOut = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(aniView, "alpha", 0f);
    fadeOut.setDuration(2000);

    ObjectAnimator mover = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(aniView, "translationX", -500f, 0f);
    mover.setInterpolator(new TimeInterpolator() {
        @Override
        public float getInterpolation(float input) {
            Log.v("MainActivity", "getInterpolation() " + String.format("%.4f", input));
            return input;
        }
    });
    mover.setDuration(2000);

    ObjectAnimator fadeIn = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(aniView, "alpha", 0f, 1f);
    fadeIn.setDuration(2000);

    AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();

    animatorSet.play(mover).with(fadeIn).after(fadeOut);
    animatorSet.start();
}
```

**Samsung Galaxy S4 (Android 4.4.2):**

```
    getInterpolation() 1,0000
    getInterpolation() 1,0000
```

**Samsung Galaxy S5 (Android 4.4.2):**

```
    getInterpolation() 0,0000
    getInterpolation() 0,0000
    getInterpolation() 0,0085
    getInterpolation() 0,0170
    getInterpolation() 0,0255
    ...
    ...
    getInterpolation() 0,9740
    getInterpolation() 0,9825
    getInterpolation() 0,9910
    getInterpolation() 0,9995
    getInterpolation() 1,0000
```

Has anyone an idea, why this doesn't work properly?

Comment: why two alpha animations? make it one and simplfy your code

Comment: fadeIn + fadeOut. But this isn't the Problem ;P

Comment: ok so whats the symptom? view doesn't move at all?

Comment: @pskink: there isn't any animation on the Galaxy S4 (e.g. Galaxy Nexus  4.2.2)

Comment: tried just animatorSet.play(mover)?

Comment: @Bino: This is also the problem on Nexus 7 (Lollipop 5.1.1), as if interpolation doesn't ever take place, and animation only happens on START and END values... Were you able to solve this somehow?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

On the Galaxy S4, under *Developer Options*, there is the option *Animator duration scale*. For some wild reason, this is *off* by default. After switching this to *1x*, my animations on the S4 started to work perfectly. This may be what is causing your problem.

Comment: may be, but this shouldn't for end users

Comment: Correct. If this was not the cause of the problem then I'm afraid I'm stumped.

Comment: This fixed it for me (although did highlight a bug in my code). Thanks for this great answer! It is worth noting that some people disable animator duration scale which can cause the same issues.

Comment: Mine is set to 1x, and I still see this issue.

Comment: @AutonomousApps, what is a device? On Samsung Galaxy S4 after turning this option to 1x an animation appeared.

Comment: @AutonomousApps, if an ObjectAnimator is not a requirement, I would recommend you to create animation with `AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.your_xml);` or `AnimationSet`. I tested both, they work. Inside xml you can also define screen coordinates like `android:toXDelta="30%p"`. With AnimationSet you can programmatically make much. If you wish, I can write an example.

Comment: @AutonomousApps Unfortunately my answer only applies to the Galaxy S4.

Comment: I've encountered this on other devices as well.

Answer (score 2):

Users can easily manipulate the scale value in Developer options or custom ROM providers. This could be a very tricky problem if you don't know what caused it in the first place.

---

**Solution**

You can just set an animation duration scale to 1 or any other pleasing value programmatically via Reflection API's capability. Thus, this will behave the same all across Android devices for your app.
Unfortunately, Android is not giving us a warning about it on its page and a solution choice rather than Reflection due to the function itself is restricted from public usage via `@hide` annotation.

For more about Android's API restriction, You could read this thread;

[What does @hide mean in the Android source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035271/what-does-hide-mean-in-the-android-source-code)

In Java

```
try {
    ValueAnimator.class.getMethod("setDurationScale", float.class).invoke(null, 1f);
} catch (Throwable t) {
    Log.e(TAG, t.getMessage());
}
```

In Kotlin

```
// You could also surround this line with try-catch block like above in Java example
ValueAnimator::class.java.getMethod("setDurationScale", Float::class.javaPrimitiveType).invoke(null, 1f)
```

I believe, this solution is more solid and robust rather than making users set it in developer settings.

Comment: People have voted this down without any comment.
I have restored justice.

Comment: Thank you @Yekta Sarıoğlu ...its working fine as i am using com.wang.avi.AVLoadingIndicatorView for progress dialoge