# ObjectAnimator.setDuration is ignored

Tags: android, animation, galaxy

The setDuration function of the `ObjectAnimator` class in Android appears to be completely ignored. No matter what value I pass it, the animation is always completed instantly.

```
    ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mView, "translationY", 0, 100)
            .setDuration(2000)
            .start();
```

The above code increases the Y value of `mView` by 100 (essentially pushing it further down the screen). The actual translation occurs correctly, however it is instantaneous. The `setDuration(2000)` is completely ignored. Why is this?

**EDIT:**

This seemsto be based on the device - the samsung galaxy s4 appears to have an issue with interpolating views correctly. This is the same issue as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25505622/androids-objectanimator-offloat-doesnt-work-properly).

Comment: seems like your UI thread is way toooooo busy

Comment: That's not the case. I have other animations which are animating very smoothly, and my UI remains responsive throughout.

Comment: ok then try differtent property name (e.g. "foo"), add setFoo(float) method in your Activity and inside setFoo call Log.d with currentTimeMillis

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with the default animation duration scale under *Developer Options*. I've answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30533502/2000012).

Comment: hahahaha been debugging this for hours without realising I had turned off the animations in the settings !!!