# ObjectAnimator ignoring duration in LayoutTransition

Tags: android, animation, objectanimator, layouttransition

My layout transition is ignoring the duration I set in `setDuration()`. No matter what value I set it to, it appears to be using the default. Here I've tried 50s, and it disappears after a few milliseconds.

```
Animator disappearingAnim = ObjectAnimator
        .ofFloat(null, "alpha", 0f)
        .setDuration(50000);

mTransitioner.setAnimator(LayoutTransition.DISAPPEARING, disappearingAnim);
mLayout.setLayoutTransition(mTransitioner);
```

The code snippet above should cause disappearing views to fade out over 50s, but instead they fade over ~300ms.

I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30377184/objectanimator-setduration-is-ignored) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25505622/androids-objectanimator-offloat-doesnt-work-properly/30533502#30533502), but I have animator scale set to 1x in developer options.

[image: Developer Options]

Comment: Same here on Nexus 5 and Pixel C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out I was laboring under a misconception about how `LayoutTransition`s work. The correct way to add a duration is the following:

```
mTransitioner.setDuration(
    LayoutTransition.DISAPPEARING, // Transition type
    disappearingAnim, 1000L        // duration in ms
);
```