# Not able to call public methods in Android TextView

Tags: java, android

I am not able to call getShowSoftInputOnFocus() while am able to call setText()? Why is this happening can someone explain???

Comment: can you please update your code without code  we are not able to help you.

Comment: its a simple object call. U can try it as well.

Comment: `getShowSoftInputOnFocus()` might be your method from your project not from `TextView` class

Comment: if we see Your code, maybe we can help You...

Comment: For those still doubting the method is there, see this (line 2430): http://osxr.org/android/source/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java

Comment: The method exists, but cannot be called as it is hidden with @hide annotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method is marked with the [@hide annotation](https://code.google.com/p/doclava/wiki/JavadocTags#@hide).

> @hide
>
> When applied to a package, class, method or field, @hide removes
> that node and all of its children from the documentation.

You can still access it via reflection as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035271/what-does-hide-mean-in-the-android-source-code).

Comment: May I ask you to accept the answer (http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you find the answer satisfactory, thus closing the question ? Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 0):

The method **getShowSoftInputOnFocus()** doesn't exist for the **TextView** class and is not in Android documentation.
How did you find this method ?

Comment: This should be a comment. And yes, the method exists, it's just hidden from the documentation...

Answer (score 0):

getShowSoftInputOnFocus() methods is not present in textview class , you can refer below link for all methods in textview class.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html