# Why does Application.class.getDeclaredFields() returns nothing?

Tags: android, reflection

Can someone please explain why  Application.class.getDeclaredFields() returns nothing?

Field[] fields = Application.class.getDeclaredFields();

The Field object is empty after the call. Are there any restrictions in java.lang.reflect that prevent this call from returning anything other than null?

Thank you

Comment: How/where are you running the code? If it's the stub android.jar you're running against, it won't contain the private fields or public fields annotated with `@hide`. `Application` has only private fields and a `@hide`-annotated field. (4.4.4_r1)

Comment: I've tried this code on a HTC Wildfire running Android 2.1 as well as on a Samsung Galaxy Core running 4.1.2.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a restriction of reflection but is expected behavior of the Reflection API.

> [`getDeclaredFields`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields()) returns .. *all the fields* declared [in this type] .. but *excludes inherited fields*.
>
> [`getFields`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getFields()) returns the *public fields* of *this class and of all its superclasses*.

The [`android.app.Application`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.7_r1/android/app/Application.java/) class *declares no fields itself* through version 2.3.7 - that is, *all fields in Application are inherited*. As such it is fitting that result of `getDeclaredFields` in such an environment is an empty array.

Version 4.x does *add a field (or fields)* marked with `@hide`; these should still [be accessible via reflection even if not listed in the javadoc/droiddoc output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035271/what-does-hide-mean-in-the-android-source-code). In this case `getDeclaredFields` should return the relevant non-inherited fields.

Comment: If I use Class.getFields() instead, I get a bunch of constants (static final some type). I'd expect all those constants with getDeclaredFields() plus any remaining private variables(provided that they exist) but getDeclaredFields returns nothing.

Comment: Thank you both. I run the code again and the method did return 3 fields on the phone running Android 4.1.2. The fields were mLoadedApk, mComponentCallbacks and mActivityLifecycleCallbacks.