# Can't import android.hardware.camera2.params.StreamConfiguration

Tags: java, android, import, android-studio

1. In Android API 21 they added `android.hardware.camera2.params.StreamConfiguration` but for some reason Android Studio can't find it.
2. Also this class (`android.hardware.camera2.params.StreamConfigurationMap`) has a public constructor and yet it says I can't create an instance of it outside its package. Why?!

Tried this:

```
StreamConfigurationMap map = new StreamConfigurationMap();  //Says can only be instantiated in its package
StreamConfiguration map = new StreamConfiguration();   //can't find StreamConfiguration
```

Comment: Do you have your compileSdkVersion set to 21?

Comment: I guess not, where and how am I supposed to define it? Manifest file?

Comment: You tagged this as android-studio, so I'm assuming you are using Gradle, in which case it should be in build.gradle in the defaultConfiguration section

Comment: Yes I am.
I dont see anything like this in my file, cant you please specify what exactly am I supposed to add? all I see are "dependencies" and "classpath" etc...

Comment: Where do you see the `StreamConfiguration` class in the documentation? I'm not seeing it. Perhaps it was in the L preview, but was removed for the final release?

Comment: As for the compileSdkVersion, is sounds like you are looking in the project-level build.gradle. You should have a module-level build.gradle as well (in the /app folder by default)

Comment: This is the map:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/params/StreamConfigurationMap.html

And as for StreamConfiguration, I got to it through the StreamConfigurationMap code...

Comment: Also I have compileSdkVersion set to 21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`StreamConfigurationMap`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/params/StreamConfigurationMap.html) does not have a public constructor.

The [`android.hardware.camera2.params`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/params/package-summary.html) package does not expose the `StreamConfiguration` class. `StreamConfigurationMap`does allow you to use a `StreamConfiguration` to obtain a configuration- the configurations available are documented [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html#SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP).

The `StreamConfiguration` class and the `StreamConfigurationMap` constructor are hidden from the public Android API using the `@hide` annotation, so you cannot use them.

Comment: That class has an @hide annotation on it. That means it is not available for you to use it. See this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17056643/1253844

Comment: I see, thank you! please edit you answer accordingly so I can accept it :)