# Cannot call public static method inside a public class

Tags: java, android

I've been trying to generate thumbnails for images and videos using Android's inbuilt `ThumbnailUtils` class. Video thumbnail generation succeeds properly via the `createVideoThumbnail(..)` method. However, I cannot even call the related method `createImageThumbnail`. Both methods are declared `public` and `static`. Here's the [github link](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/media/java/android/media/ThumbnailUtils.java) to the source.

How is it possible to restrict clients from using a `public static` method selectively in Java?

[Edit]: See [this link](https://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-1-introduction/) for more info about using Android's internal/hidden methods:

Comment: "I cannot even call the related method createImageThumbnail" - which result do you get? compile-time, run-time?

Comment: Compile time. (eclipse complains "The method createImageThumbnail(String, int) is undefined for the type ThumbnailUtils")

Comment: means you have to call public static method inside public class ? am i right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for [createImageThumbnail](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/media/java/android/media/ThumbnailUtils.java#L82) contains the `@hide` which makes it not callable outside of the Android SDK.

More information about `@hide` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035271/what-does-hide-mean-in-the-android-source-code).

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Now, how do I use `@hide` for my functions? It doesn't seem to work for my functions.

Comment: You can't call it directly. You have to use reflection to do so. See the second link in my answer for an example.

Comment: No, i meant how do I hide my custom methods? (I read your link and was able to call the method via reflection)

Comment: Oh sorry. I don't know. I never tried to do it myself. Try asking a new question for that.