# android.media package missing few classes in sdk-platforms[android.jar]

Tags: android, android-audiomanager, fm-radio

I am trying to build a FM Radio kind of application and I cloned this [Google Respository](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/FMRadio/+/master/src/com/android/fmradio) for the reference.

However There are few classes in the imports which are missing in android sdk. I tried changing compileSdkVersion from 18 to 24 but android.jar seems to be missing these Following imports:

```
import android.media.AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener;
import android.media.AudioManager.OnAudioPortUpdateListener;
import android.media.AudioMixPort;
import android.media.AudioPatch;
import android.media.AudioPort;
import android.media.AudioPortConfig;
import android.media.AudioDevicePort;
import android.media.AudioDevicePortConfig;
```

Where exactly are these classes and how can i import them ?

```
The Strange thing about them is they are present as .java files in sources/android-xx but not in actual .jar file.
```

The sample is showing errors and I am not able to proceed. Please guide me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: I am facing same issue. If you find any solution or hack then please help me with this @dheerajbansal.90@gmail.com. 
thanks in advance.

Comment: @ Amritpal Singh, DheerubhaiBansal, I am also facing same issue any luck on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can see from the Android source code that these classes are "hidden" from the `jar` using the "pseudo-annotation":

```
/* @hide */
```

For example, see [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/media/java/android/media/AudioManager.java#919) and [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/media/java/android/media/AudioPatch.java#30).

This annotation controls what will appear in the runtime `Android.jar`.

Note, sometimes these *hidden* classes are later included as part of the official SDK.

**Refer to:**

https://commonsware.com/blog/2018/01/18/think-hard-about-hide.html

[What does @hide mean in the Android source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035271/what-does-hide-mean-in-the-android-source-code)

[What exactly does Android's @hide annotation do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31908205/what-exactly-does-androids-hide-annotation-do)