# Android Studio throws errors while using SerialManager and SerialPort API

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

I'm trying to use SerialManager and SerialPort APIs to read from a device node. Android studio says that it cannot resolve the symbol for both these APIs.What are my chances to use this API in Studio? I'm using Android SDK version 25 BTW.

Answer (score 1):

Both classes [SerialManager](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/hardware/SerialManager.java) and [SerialPort](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/hardware/SerialPort.java) are [**hidden**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035271/what-does-hide-mean-in-the-android-source-code), so you can not access it. See below for declarations of both classes

```
/**
 * @hide
 */
public class SerialManager {
.....
}
```

and

```
/**
 * @hide
 */
public class SerialPort {
...
}
```

---

Other ref :

1. [Access via Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035271/what-does-hide-mean-in-the-android-source-code)
2. [What exactly does Android's @hide annotation do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31908205/what-exactly-does-androids-hide-annotation-do)