# Is it possible to modify NativeActivity.java for my app's purposes

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have an NDK Android app based on NativeActivity Android sample, and I need to change slightly a behavior of `NativeActivity`. I cannot do it by subclassing (inheriting), because the thing that I want to change is not exposed.

Therefore, my idea was to take source code of *NativeActivity.java*, re-work it a bit and then rename it as say *MyNativeActivity.java* and use it in manifest instead of `NativeActivity`.

So I took source code for from *Android\sdk\sources\android-25\android\app\NativeActivity.java*, renamed it as *MyNativeActivity.java* and inserted into my project. But when I tried to compile it, I got errors:

```
Error:(179, 41) error: cannot find symbol method getLdLibraryPath()
Error:(200, 70) error: cannot find symbol method getNativePtr()
Error:(295, 59) error: cannot find symbol method getNativePtr()
Error:(301, 61) error: cannot find symbol method getNativePtr()
```

And I cannot find these `getLdLibraryPath()` and `getNativePtr()` in the source code folder (*Android\sdk\sources\android-25*)

My question is if it's possible to use Android source code in my project, and how to deal with problems like this?

Answer (score 1):

> My question is if it's possible to use Android source code in my project

It depends on the scope and contents of the source code.

> But when I tried to compile it, I got errors:

Those are references to `native` methods. You would need to find the JNI code that implements the functions behind those methods and add that to your NDK project, then modify `MyNativeActivity.java` to refer to your library.

I do not hold out a lot of hope that this will prove to be practical.

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned methods are annotated with [@hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31908205/what-exactly-does-androids-hide-annotation-do) in the source code which means they are stripped from the Android SDK .jars. They should still be available at runtime. You can call them using reflection, like this:

```
private static long callGetNativePtrOnInputQueue(InputQueue inputQueue) {

    Class clazz = Class.forName("android.view.InputQueue");
    Method method = clazz.getMethod("getNativePtr");
    Object returnValue = method.invoke(inputQueue);

    if(returnValue instanceof  Long)
        return ((Long)returnValue).longValue();

    return 0;
}
```

However, these methods are not part of the public API and there's a potential danger of them being removed/renamed in the future.