# Problems with random fragment in android

Tags: java, android, random, fragment

I've got an activity which should show a random fragment.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import java.util.Random;
import android.support.v4.app.*;

public class RandomActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private Random1 random1;
private Random2 random2;
private Random3 random3;
private Random4 random4;
private Random5 random5;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_random);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    initUI();
}

private void initUI() {
    FragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().openTransaction();
    setRandomFragment();
}

private void setRandomFragment() {
    Random random = new Random();
    int randomFragmentNum = random.nextInt(250);
    if (randomFragmentNum < 50) {
        randomFragmentNum = 0;
    } else if (randomFragmentNum >= 50 && randomFragmentNum < 100) {
        randomFragmentNum = 1;
    } else if (randomFragmentNum >= 100 && randomFragmentNum < 150) {
        randomFragmentNum = 2;
    } else if (randomFragmentNum >= 150 && randomFragmentNum < 200) {
        randomFragmentNum = 3;
    } else if (randomFragmentNum >= 200 && randomFragmentNum <= 250) {
        randomFragmentNum = 4;
    }

    switch (randomFragmentNum) {
        case 0: {
            random1 = new Random1();
            FragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frag_rand_home, random1);
            FragmentTransaction.commit()
            break;
        }
        case 1: {
            random2 = new Random2();
            FragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frag_rand_home, random2);
            FragmentTransaction.commit()
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            random3 = new Random3();
            FragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frag_rand_home, random3);
            FragmentTransaction.commit()
            break;
        }
        case 3: {
            random4 = new Random4();
            FragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frag_rand_home, random4);
            FragmentTransaction.commit()
            break;
        }
        case 4: {
            random5 = new Random5();
            FragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frag_rand_home, random5);
            FragmentTransaction.commit()
            break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

So that's my code but I still get some errors :-(

Here error number 1:

```
private void initUI() {
    FragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().openTransaction();
    setRandomFragment();
}
```

> Expression expected | FragmentManager.openTransaction can only be called from within the same library group (groupId=com.android.support).
>   This API has been flagged with a restriction that has not been met.  Examples of API restrictions: * Method can only be invoked by a subclass * Method can only be accessed from within the same library (defined by the Gradle library group id) .* Method can only be accessed from tests. . You can add your own API restrictions with the @RestrictTo annotation.

Here error number 2 (on case 0,1,2,3,4 the same):

```
case 0: {
            random1 = new Random1();
            FragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frag_rand_home, random1);
            FragmentTransaction.commit()
            break;
        }
```

> Non-static method 'add(int, android.support.v4.app.Fragment)' cannot be referenced from a static context. | Non-static method 'commit()' cannot be referenced from a static context.

I'm stucking on this two errors since some hours and but I still don't know how to fix them.

It would be very nice if somebody can help me with my problems...
Best regards
Jeremy

Comment: I suggest you learn about arrays and `List`. When you start naming variables with numbers on the end, then you should look at other possible solutions. With an array, you can reduce `setRandomFragment()` to two lines of code.

Comment: You should also just do `int randomFragmentNum = random.nextInt(5);` then you don't need the `if...else` chain.

Comment: `FragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().openTransaction();` this line does not make sense. its like `String = "hello";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thank you very much for your attention and help! Now I was able to find a solution for myself. I think it's posssible to do this with less code but it works!

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import java.util.Random;
import android.support.v4.app.*;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

public class RandomActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private Random1 random1;
private Random2 random2;
private Random3 random3;
private Random4 random4;
private Random5 random5;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_random);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    FragmentTransaction fm = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    initUI();
}

private void initUI() {
    setRandomFragment();
}

private void setRandomFragment() {
    Random random = new Random();
    int randomFragmentNum = random.nextInt(250);
    if (randomFragmentNum < 50) {
        randomFragmentNum = 0;
    } else if (randomFragmentNum >= 50 && randomFragmentNum < 100) {
        randomFragmentNum = 1;
    } else if (randomFragmentNum >= 100 && randomFragmentNum < 150) {
        randomFragmentNum = 2;
    } else if (randomFragmentNum >= 150 && randomFragmentNum < 200) {
        randomFragmentNum = 3;
    } else if (randomFragmentNum >= 200 && randomFragmentNum <= 250) {
        randomFragmentNum = 4;
    }

    switch (randomFragmentNum) {
        case 0: {
            random1 = new Random1();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frag_rand_home, random1, "Home");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            break;
        }
        case 1: {
            random2 = new Random2();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frag_rand_home, random2, "Home");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            random3 = new Random3();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frag_rand_home, random3, "Home");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            break;
        }
        case 3: {
            random4 = new Random4();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frag_rand_home, random4, "Home");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            break;
        }
        case 4: {
            random5 = new Random5();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frag_rand_home, random5, "Home");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an instance averrable instead of using it with class as

```
FragmentTransaction fm = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

and since you want to use it inside other methods so

```
private FragmentTransaction fm;
private void initUI() {
    FragmentTransaction fm = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    setRandomFragment();
}
```

later

```
case 0: {
        random1 = new Random1();
        fm(R.id.frag_rand_home, random1);
        fm()
        break;
    }
```

Note: `openTransaction()` should be `beginTransaction()` and you have to get a new instance of transaction before loading another fragment and also use `replace` to change fragment second time and later

> FragmentManager.openTransaction can only be called from within the
>   same library group (groupId=com.android.support)

From the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/cef09fe/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.java) the `opentransaction` has been deprecated so no longer in use and not even there in docs as well but internally it does call `beginTranscation` and also it is applied with @hide annotation so seems like you are using some old android platform to build your app

Reference :

[What exactly does Android's @hide annotation do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31908205/what-exactly-does-androids-hide-annotation-do)

[Difference between add(), replace(), and addToBackStack()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18634207/difference-between-add-replace-and-addtobackstack)

Comment: There's still  FragmentManager.openTransaction can only be called from within the same library group (groupId=com.android.support)...

Comment: @JeremyBrehe I am unable to find the documentation of `openTransaction` so I don't know what it is

Comment: from the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/cef09fe/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.java) the `opentransaction` has been deprecated so no longer in use and not even there in docs as well but internally it does call `beginTranscation` and also it is applied with @hide annotation so seems like you are using some old android platform to build your app