# Missing android method: ScanRecord.parseFromBytes

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I was looking through the source code for android 22 to change my code to the new BLE scanning and came across the ScanRecord class. When I opened the source code for ScanRecord (sources/android-22/android/bluetooth/le/ScanRecord.java) I saw that there is a function parseFromBytes:

```
/**
 * Parse scan record bytes to {@link ScanRecord}.
 * <p>
 * The format is defined in Bluetooth 4.1 specification, Volume 3, Part C, Section 11 and 18.
 * <p>
 * All numerical multi-byte entities and values shall use little-endian <strong>byte</strong>
 * order.
 *
 * @param scanRecord The scan record of Bluetooth LE advertisement and/or scan response.
 * @hide
 */
 public static ScanRecord parseFromBytes(byte[] scanRecord)
```

But if I try and use it in my code, it cannot find the function. Also if I check the API [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanRecord.html#pubmethods), the function is not mentioned at all.

I am using Android Studio 1.3.1 with compileSdkVersion 22, minSdkVersion 18, targetSdkVersion 22 and buildToolsVersion 22.0.1

What am I missing? Why can't I use the function although it is part of the android source code?

Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 3):

ScanRecord class was added in API level 21.
You can get an instance of it from [ScanResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanResult.html#getScanRecord()) 
Code:

```
ScanCallback leScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
        ScanRecord record = result.getScanRecord();
    }
}
```

On that object instance the public functions are available.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't really answer my question. I asked why the parseFromBytes function is not accessible even though it is declared as public static and not how I can access the ScanRecord from the ScanResult.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and wanted to use ScanRecord.parseFromBytes. After lots of googling I noticed it has the tag "@hide" which effectively hides it from the compiler. See [What does @hide mean in the Android source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035271/what-does-hide-mean-in-the-android-source-code)

I'm in two minds to use reflection, but I want access to the fields in ScanRecord (e.g. TxPower)

Comment: A thanks that explains it. I ended up writing my own parse function since I was only really interested in one field of the ScanRecord.