# Why can't one access getFrameTime() in Choreographer Class?

Tags: java, android

```
package android.view;
public final class Choreographer {
...
    public long getFrameTime() {
        return getFrameTimeNanos() / TimeUtils.NANOS_PER_MS;
    }
...
}
```

I can't see the reason why I get the error message `Error:(195, 50) error: cannot find symbol method getFrameTime()` with `Choreographer.getInstance().getFrameTime()`

build.gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 23
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the [method](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/Choreographer.java#L494) is annotated with [@Hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035271/what-does-hide-mean-in-the-android-source-code).
Access through reflection is still possible though.