# android ActivityOptions.isReturning() NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

In which case I have

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'boolean android.app.ActivityOptions.isReturning()' on a null object
>   reference

I cannot understand why `EnterActivityOptions.isReturning()` in [ActivityTransitionState](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/777f5b2/core/java/android/app/ActivityTransitionState.java#196) give me null?

Comment: Please have a look through this : [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: where did you find `isReturning()` method ?

Comment: in ActivityTransitionState.java

Comment: can you refer a link

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/777f5b2/core/java/android/app/ActivityTransitionState.java#196

Comment: You need to add more context to your question. The `ActivityOptions.isReturning` method is not part of the public API neither is the `ActivityTransitionState` you referenced.

Comment: please improve this question,  its really hard to understand how you are even using a hidden api.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035271/what-does-hide-mean-in-the-android-source-code

Answer (score 4):

Try with support library `24.1.0` (released today, but not sure if this fix your problem)

Comment: I just tried using 24.1.0 but maybe its not live yet. Because it couldn't find the design library.

Comment: weird since the changelog is already there https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html

Comment: Now its live.  But that doesn't fix this issue.

Comment: It crashes with this statement `getActivity().supportStartPostponedEnterTransition();`

Comment: Looks like `getActivity()` is returning null, where are you calling that? are you using fragments right?

Comment: I am using fragments.  getActivity() is not returning null.  For some reason the activityoptions are null but i explicitly set them when starting a new activity.

Comment: I added a try {} catch(NullPointerException e){} to catch this exception and then it proceeds as usual without an issue.  still not sure why its throwing this exception.  In my case it will get thrown on a Samsung S5 and not a Nexus 5X.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is with the variable `EnterActivityOptions`
When I look into your code sample it's look like you assigned some value to `EnterActivityOptions` in the method of `setEnterActivityOptions`

But I am not sure that this method is calling when you invoke the activity.

if it's not calling the method then obviously it will not be initialized and the variable value will be null this results NullPointerException.

So, to resolve this issue please try to check the case whether `EnterActivityOptions` is null or not and then use the condition

```
if (mEnterActivityOptions.isReturning()) {
    Your code will place here
}
```

Answer (score -2):

On API 21, only one call to `startPostponedEnterTransition` is allowed