# Cannot find symbol method setDropDownAnimationStyle(int) in AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

When i use

```
 AutoCompleteTextView search_edit = (AutoCompleteTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.auto_search);
    search_edit.setDropDownAnimationStyle(R.style.MedicineListDropDown);
```

i get Cannot find method setDropDownAnimationStyle(int) but according to the android [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/47fb191/core/java/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.java) there is a public method

```
 public void setDropDownAnimationStyle(int animationStyle) {
    mPopup.setAnimationStyle(animationStyle);
}
```

so why am i getting error?

Comment: Maybe your version of the library does not have the method?

Comment: @SelçukCihan What version is used in the link given above, so that i can use the method.

Comment: Checked it now, you can not use the method because it has not made its way into the api yet. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you are trying to use is marked as hidden (pending API council approval). That is why you can not use it.

```
 /**
 * <p>Sets the animation style of the auto-complete drop-down list.</p>
 *
 * <p>If the drop-down is showing, calling this method will take effect only
 * the next time the drop-down is shown.</p>
 *
 * @param animationStyle animation style to use when the drop-down appears
 *      and disappears.  Set to -1 for the default animation, 0 for no
 *      animation, or a resource identifier for an explicit animation.
 *
 * @hide Pending API council approval
 */
```

- See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035271/what-does-hide-mean-in-the-android-source-code) for info on @hide. It describes a way to use the method, but that is **strongly advised against**.
- [Official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html) for `AutoCompleteTextView`.