# Why i can't access the definition of some java class?

Tags: java, android

under android framework i have these files :

```
file: android.widget.Editor
package android.widget;
/**
 * Helper class used by TextView to handle editable text views.
 *
 * @hide
 */
public class Editor {
....
}
```

and

```
file: android.widget.TextView
package android.widget;
@RemoteView
public class TextView extends View implements ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener {

}
```

but i can't understand why in my unit i can do

- import android.widget.TextView

but i can't do

- import android.widget.Editor

how can i access the unit android.widget.Editor ?

Comment: see the @hide annotation? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035271/what-does-hide-mean-in-the-android-source-code

Comment: thanks Bene :) i understand now, just i don't know how to access hidden class via reflection :(

Comment: You should probably use a different View. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: i want to debut the Editor :( add some Log info a little everywhere inside to understand what it's not working for me ...