# Android - IContentService cannot be resolved

Tags: android, android-studio, import, android-contentresolver

In my project I need to use IContentService, and I've used the right import (import android.content.IContentService) and yet android studio tells me 'Cannot resolve symbol IContentService'.

I know IContentService is an actual class, because it is used in ContentResolver.getContentService();

Anyone know how I can get this import to work?

Comment: "android studio tells me 'Cannot resolve symbol IContentService'" -- that is because there is no `IContentService` in the Android SDK. "I need to use IContentService" -- why? It is part of the internal implementation of Android. It is not guaranteed to exist, unmodified, in all versions of Android and may be modified by device manufacturers or custom ROM developers.

Comment: Which API level are you using that you can call `ContentResolver.getContentService()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use this class directly.

You can see in the source code (e.g. [here for Marshmallow](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/marshmallow-release/core/java/android/content/IContentService.aidl)) that this class is tagged with the `@hide` annotation.

The class can only be used by reflection as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17056643/4571082) (with all it's disadvantages).

BTW: `ContentResolver.getContentService()` is also a hidden method (see [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/marshmallow-release/core/java/android/content/ContentResolver.java)).