# change visibility of method on the basis of sdk android

Tags: java, android

Suppose I developed an android library **XYZ** which has methods 
**animateWithTransition()** which has code related with Transition api(i.e. minsdk=21)
**animateSimply()** which has simple animation.

When Client uses **XYZ** library, he should be able to see **animateWithTransition()** as a suggestion(ctrl+space) if his **minsdk < 21.**
and should be able to see only **animateSimply()**
: |

How to go about this?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?  As a user of libraries, I don't want one function to call if I'm API< 21 and another for API >21.  I want one call, and you should figure out which version to do.

Comment: I'd like to achieve that for avoiding my clients time in writing boilerplate code to figure out versions.. There is annotation @hide wh\ich completely hides method https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035271/what-does-hide-mean-in-the-android-source-code

Comment: You can use the RequiresApi annotation. See [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/RequiresApi.html)

Comment: @AskQ If you want clients to avoid writing boilerplate, then do what I suggested-  1 method, which does a version lookup and chooses which branch of code to use.  Then there's no boilerplate, and no confusion about which function to use.

Comment: @GabeSechan, Kunal Thanks its simple solution. But may be visibility logic is possible with java reflection or some custom annotation processor. I'm looking for that.

Answer (score 2):

You should try structuring your code in the following manner -

```
    public void performAnimation() {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21 )
         { 
      // write code for animateSimply function here 
           }
    else
         { 
      // write code for animateWithTransition function here 
           }
        }
```

That ways, you'll have a single function (which means less code, clean code), and easier testing. Plus your client has to call only 1 function, which makes it easier for him/her to use your library.