# Can't resolve NetworkUtils

Tags: android

I'm trying to use NetworkUtils class in android and it shows the error like in the following image, how is this even possible?
[image]

Comment: `NetworkUtils` is not a public API. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035271/what-does-hide-mean-in-the-android-source-code

Comment: Still can't figure out how to import it, can you tell me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're talking about the [Udacity class](https://github.com/udacity/ud851-Exercises/blob/student/Lesson02-GitHub-Repo-Search/T02.04-Exercise-ConnectingToTheInternet/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/datafrominternet/utilities/NetworkUtils.java) and not the built-in Android class because the latter doesn't have a method called `buildUrl()` (and isn't public as mentioned in the comments).

In that case, you should make sure you:

1. Have `NetworkUtils.java` in your source code
2. Properly import it at the top of your file like in [the example](https://github.com/udacity/ud851-Exercises/blob/student/Lesson02-GitHub-Repo-Search/T02.04-Exercise-ConnectingToTheInternet/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/datafrominternet/MainActivity.java#L25) with `import com.example.android.datafrominternet.utilities.NetworkUtils;` (unless you moved it to another package)

If the file is already in the source code, or in a library you are using, you can also hit Alt+Enter while the cursor is on the error. It should open a quick fix window. The first option should be importing the class from the appropriate place.

Comment: Thank you man I just didn't notice this a user-defined class, I thought it was built-in,it's just I'm writing the code myself, didn't download the project, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using

```
compile 'com.blankj:utilcode:1.5.0'
```

`AndroidUtils` lib for common utils.

If you are using this lib then you have to write below line in `Application` class

```
`com.blankj.utilcode.util.Utils.init(this); `
```

Comment: Thanks bro @kichik helped me with what I needed.