# How to determine input device is external

Tags: android

I'm looking for a way to identify the input device that is external.

I notice the Android API for [InputDevice] class have a function called [isExternal]. But when I tried to use it, it tells me that it cannot resolve method. I check the online API reference and notice that the function does not exist. So I wonder why is the function in the API but not in the online reference.

Reference:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/InputDevice.html
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/InputDevice.java

Comment: Did you find any possibility of checking that without using reflection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

isExternal is a hidden method that is not accessible through the SDK. However, you can still invoke it using java reflection.

```
public boolean isExternal(InputDevice inputDevice) {
    try {
        Method m = InputDevice.class.getMethod("isExternal");
        return (Boolean) m.invoke(inputDevice);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

source: [What does @hide mean in the Android source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035271/what-does-hide-mean-in-the-android-source-code)

Comment: Since Android api 29 this method is fully accessible without reflection :)
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/InputDevice#isExternal()