# Why are constants in SignalStrength hidden?

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I use `SignalStength` to get the quality of the signal, before sending sms:

```
signalStrength.getLevel()
```

I then wanted to compare the integer with a static constant in SignalStength:

```
if (signalStrengthLevel == SignalStrength.SIGNAL_STRENGTH_POOR) {
    //...
}
```

But it doesn't compile in *Android Studio*. I realized that for some reason, these constants are marked as hidden in the source code:

```
/** @hide */
public static final int SIGNAL_STRENGTH_POOR
        = TelephonyProtoEnums.SIGNAL_STRENGTH_POOR; // = 1
```

Which forces me to copy/paste these constants in one of my own classes...

I then wonder if anyone knows the reason why the developers decided to mark these constants as hidden?

Comment: I doubt you're going to get a definitive answer unless, for some reason, one of the developers at Google that were involved in writing/reviewing that particular piece of code decides to come here and anwer your question. I would say, if something is marked `@hide`, it's typically to discourage app developers from making use of those symbols. There could be various reasons for wanting to discourage that. Perhaps you have a set of constants that isn't stable and could change from one Android version to another.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation of the [`TelephonyManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager), we can find [`getSignalStrength()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getSignalStrength()) method, which returns [`SignalStrength`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SignalStrength) type, which has [`getLevel()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SignalStrength.html#getLevel()) method. In the documentation of [`getLevel()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SignalStrength.html#getLevel()) method, we can read the following information about returned integer value:

> a single integer from 0 to 4 representing the general signal quality.
>   This may take into account many different radio technology inputs. 0
>   represents very poor signal strength while 4 represents a very strong
>   signal strength.

Taking that into consideration, I'd solve that in the following way:
create static values like:

```
private final static int VERY_POOR_SIGNAL = 0;
private final static int POOR_SIGNAL = 1;
private final static int MEDIUM_SIGNAL = 2;
private final static int STRONG_SIGNAL = 3;
private final static int VERY_STRONG_SIGNAL = 4;
```

and use this values to compare them with the integer value returned by:

```
telephonyManager.getSignalStrength().getLevel()
```

Comment: Yes I wrote "Which forces me to copy/paste these constants in one of my own classes...". Ofc I can just copy/paste these constants in one of my classes, just as you suggested as well. But the question really is: why did they decide to mark these constants as hidden in SIgnalStrength

Comment: that is basically what user2923322 did : `Which forces me to copy/paste these constants in one of my own classes...`, and he is asking `Why are constants in SignalStrength hidden?`, therefore your answer does not answer the question.

Comment: Ok, I don't know why these constants are hidden. I just provided the feasible solution to deal with this issue. Maybe developers of Android Framework had some reason to do that related to their internal development process. I think, in this case due to lack of documentation ,only Android Platform Developers could answer that question...

Answer (score 0):

The word `/** @hide */` just informs that the API is not accessible from SDK. I think it might be for security reasons.

[Check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035271/what-does-hide-mean-in-the-android-source-code)