# How do I subclass the Javadoc Doclet available in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, javadoc

I need to hide certain public functions from the API. I cannot mark them as deprecated and hide them, as I still need the docs to show description for real deprecated methods. After a bit of searching, I'm sure my solution is a Doclet that subclasses the default Doclet used in Android Studio, But I don't know how to do this

Edit: I tried using the @hide tag, but the tag is not supported by the default Doclet used by Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to subclass anything. Just use @hide annotation. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17056643/6134394)

Comment: I tried this, but Javadoc throws error saying "error: unknown tag: hide"

Comment: I tried using Doclava, but I get another error saying -splitindex param is unreecognized