# BluetoothDevice.aliasName unresolved reference

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, bluetooth

Kotlin noob here.

When I `ctrl+click` on `BluetoothDevice` it opens...

`\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-28\android\bluetooth\BluetoothDevice.java`

In there I can see...

```
public String getAliasName()
```

Yet I'm unable to access it in my `ScanCallback`. Why not?

[image]

I have `minSdkVersion` set to 28.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method is annotated with `@hide`, so it means it's not available in public API. Read more about it here: [What does @hide mean in the Android source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035271/what-does-hide-mean-in-the-android-source-code)